# Метод Invoke для textBox

Tags: c#, .net

Привет!

У меня есть `textBox` , и многопоточное приложение.

В каждом из потоков выполняется проверка, и в зависимости от её результатов выводится строка в `textBox`.

Например такая функция:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)){
            url = textBox1.Text;
            playerNum = 1;
            Thread thr = new Thread(CheckProfile);
            thr.Start();
        }
```

И таких у меня одновременно 10 штук. В каждую из них передаётся уникальное значение `url`

И теперь в функции `CheckProfile()` мне нужно добавить строку в элемент `textBoxLog`

```
 private void CheckProfile()
    {
     string _url = url;
     if(_url == '1') {
            textBoxLog.Text = "Равен 1";
         } else if(_url == '2') {
                textBoxLog.Text = "Равен 2";
             }
    }
```

Я не смогу добавить строку, если выполняется другой поток.

Вопрос: Как для такой простой функции добавить метод Invoke?

И дополнительный вопрос: Как в поток передать значение переменной `url` ?

Comment: Делайте через async/await, и подобных проблем возникать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Передать в поток значение переменной `url` можно через [параметризованный](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) запуск потока, например так:

```
var thread = new Thread(u => CheckProfile((string)u));
thread.Start(url);
```

или с использованием [замыканий](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx), например так:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => CheckProfile(url));
thread.Start();
```

А установить свойство `text` из другого потока можно попросив сам `TextBox` [сделать это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) в том потоке, в котором он был создан, например:

```
private void CheckProfile(string url)
{
    if (textBoxLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBoxLog.Invoke(new Action(() => CheckProfile(url)));
        return;
    }

     if (url == "1")
        textBoxLog.Text = "Равен 1";
    else if (url == "2")
        textBoxLog.Text = "Равен 2";
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли `else` после `if (textBoxLog.InvokeRequired)`.

Comment: @andreycha Действительно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Очень просто:

```
var uri = "test.com";
textBox1.Invoke(() => {
     //этот код будет выполнен в потоке в котором создавалась кнопка
     textBox1.Text = uri;
});
```